# Access to the first element of a Foreman's yaml

Tags: ruby, templates, puppet, theforeman

Im trying to get one element from a yaml structure which come from Foreman, the yaml is like this:

```
nodes:
   host1:
      ip: xxx.xxx.xxx
      cdir: bbb.bbb.bbb
      interface: aaa
   host2:
      ip: yyy.yyy.yyy
      cdir: bbb.bbb.bbb
      interface: aaa
```

This yaml is declarated on a Foreman,and it uses in a template:

```
<%= @nodes[0][name] %> IPaddr2::<%= @nodes[0]['ip'] %>/<%= @nodes[0]['cidr'] %>/<%= @nodes[0]['interface'] -%>
```

And its defined on a manifest:

```
class heartbeat {
   template_resources => 'site/heartbeat/resources.erb'
}
```

I only need the first element to apply, in this case. Thanks for the fast answer.

Cheers

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

```
<% key = @nodes.keys[0] -%>
<%= key %> IPaddr2::<%= @nodes[key]['ip'] %>/<%= @nodes[key]['cidr'] %>/<%= @nodes[key]['interface'] %>
```

Cheers